# Using a <button> and getElementsByClassName () to change the color of all the <p> in my document

Tags: javascript, button, styles, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use a  with js script on HTML to change the color of all the paragraphs in my document.

So far I have used:
`<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph').style.color='white'">white Font all</button>`

and also

`<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('p').style.color='white'">white Font all</button>`

but it doesn't seem to work. I want to change the color of  all the paragraph fonts in my document to white, or any color. I used ID and it works fine for 1 paragraph, but I need all of them at the same time.

`<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementsById('intro').style.color='white'">white Font Intro</button>`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that ClassName and TagName return a collection of elements rather than a single element. You must loop through the collection to change the style of all elements.

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeColor('white')">White Font All</button>

<script>
  function changeColor(color) {
    const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.color = color;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByClassName returns array not a single element.

a sample:

```js
// example 1
document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph').forEach(p => p.style.color = 'white');

// example 2
let p = document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph');
for(let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  p[i].style.color = 'white';
}
```